# drupal 8 routing yml entity_access

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

in a module.routing.yml file in drupal 8,
Where is the function "node.view" like in

**_entity_access: 'node.view'**

source :
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!book!book.routing.yml/8

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Simply put, `_entity_access: node.view` in a `module.routing.yml` file in Drupal 8 means "call the access handler defined in the `node` entity and supply `view` as the operation for which access is being checked".

The access handler is defined in the `access` handler entry in the entity type annotation. E.g. for Node entity

```
/**
 * Defines the node entity class.
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "node",
 *   label = @Translation("Content"),
 *   bundle_label = @Translation("Content type"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "access" = "Drupal\node\NodeAccessControlHandler",
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

So viewing the code at the callback `\Drupal\node\NodeAccessControlHandler::access()`, the `$operation` parameter holds the value `'view'`.

```
public function access(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, $langcode = LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_DEFAULT, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
  $account = $this->prepareUser($account);

  if ($account->hasPermission('bypass node access')) {
    $result = AccessResult::allowed()->cachePerPermissions();
    return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
  }
  if (!$account->hasPermission('access content')) {
    $result = AccessResult::forbidden()->cachePerPermissions();
    return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
  }
  $result = parent::access($entity, $operation, $langcode, $account, TRUE)->cachePerPermissions();
  return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
}
```